# combine values of a parameter in reporting services 2008

Tags: sql, join, reporting-services, parameters, vbscript

Hi I have a parameter called 'SiteOfClinic' which lists down few site

1. OHH YAC
2. DHH Paeds
3. QHH YAC
4. TRP Paeds
5. MJH Paeds

It works fine so far, but now i want to combine the top two (option 1 and 2) together, so i created another label  'OHH YAC/DHH Paeds' but I dont know what to put in the expression to combain the two.

i have tried the following but unsuccessfull

```
=SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!HospitalSite.Value,"'OHH YAC,DHH Paeds"),"'OHH YAC,DHH Paeds")
```

and

```
=JOIN(Parameters!HospitalSite.Value,"OHH YAC,DHH Paeds")
```

please help, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> ' Assuming "SiteOfClinic" (aka "Parameters!HospitalSite.Value")
>> ' is an array containing 3 string values:
>> SiteOfClinic = Array("A 0", "B 1", "C 2")
>> ' and you want an array holding the first two items, you have to create a copy:
>> Copy = SiteOfClinic
>> ' and keep just the first two items
>> ReDim Preserve Copy(1)
>> ' Use Join(array, separator) to build a string from Copy
>> s = Join(Copy, "<>")
>> WScript.Echo s
>> or Split(string, separator) to get an array from s
>> a = Split(s, "<>")
>> WScript.Echo CStr(UBound(Copy)=UBound(a)), CStr(a(0)=Copy(0))
>>
A 0<>B 1
True True
```